# How to pass the values of a dropDownList in the clientside to a webmethod through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webmethod

I have a textbox and a dropdownlist on my client side. I need to pass the values of these controls to a webmethod (in the code behind) using javascript.
I can pass the textbox value but not the dropdownlist.

```
<p><asp:DropDownList id="ddlList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></p>
<p><asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"  OnTextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged"    OnKeyPress="onKeyFunction();" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:GridView ID="grdLista" runat="server"></asp:GridView>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onKeyFunction() {
        var search = document.getElementById('<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>').value;
        //var ddl = i need to pass the dropdownlist values here..
        PageMethods.callJS(search, /*ddl */, onSucess, onError);

        function onSucess(result) {
            alert(result);
        }

        function onError(result) {
            alert('Something wrong.');
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is the code in my WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]            
public static IEnumerable<string> callJS(string search)
{
    IEnumerable<string> results = itemList.Where(item => item.Contains(search.ToLower()));
    return (results);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of your DDL like this :

```
var liste =  document.getElementById('#ddlList');
var ddl = liste.options[liste.selectedIndex].value;
```

---

**EDIT :**

In order to retrieve all the values from a DDL, we have to loop over the options values:

```
var ddl = [];
for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) {
    ddl.push(document.getElementById("<%=ddlList.ClientID %>").options[i].value);
}
```

This array can be get at server side as a `List<string>`:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static IEnumerable<string> callJS(List<string> ddl) { ... }
```

Comment: The thing is that i need all the values of the ddl because i use them in the WebMethod. My webmethod its supposed to sort the items in the ddl using the search value.

Comment: It was just what I was looking for, i had several days stuck with that, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not clear where in the page method the ddl values are used. perhaps you haven't written that part yet. as a suggestion you can pass all the values as comma separated string. or as an array.

using Jquery the values can be taken like this:

```
function getDropDownList() {
        var $ddl = $('#' + 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlList');
        var $array = []
        $ddl.children('option').each(function () {
            $array.push($(this)[0].value);

        })
        //return $array you can return the value here as an array;
 //return $array.join(',') or as a string;

        try {
            PageMethods.callJS(search,$array, success, failure);
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert('error');
        }

}
```

Page Method signature will need a change.

```
[WebMethod]            
public static IEnumerable<string> callJS(string search, string[] ddlList)
    {



        IEnumerable<string> results = itemList.Where(item => item.Contains(search.ToLower()));
        return (results);
    }
```

Hope this helps.